# CSS not displaying properly in Sharepoint on Edge Browser (SEC7111 Error)

Tags: html, css, security, sharepoint, microsoft-edge

Hopefully I can explain this correctly. I have recently been moved to a Windows 10 VM from Windows 7 and I'm trying to get a site for my team at work to display properly in Edge. I have a WebPart linking to CSS that is displaying everything as one large list instead of a table with dropdowns. When I open the HTML page on its own in Edge it displays fine, but with code in SharePoint it is not working correctly. Any ideas of why this could happen?
[What should display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkKq4.png)

[What is displaying in SharePoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe3pJ.png)

**EDIT**
After opening developer tools I find that I am receiving a SEC7111 error code on my CSS file that is being linked. Looking other places for solutions to this too, but any help is greatly appreciated!

**FINAL EDIT**
With the SEC7111 error I found out that the "file://" links I used for the CSS weren't going to work because they weren't considered "secure" (Although I got the same error in IE, but never had this display issue..?) So, I moved my linked CSS file to a secure folder in another SharePoint site I have, linked the CSS from there, and now it's working!

Comment: From the screenshot and your description, it seems that the CSS file not load successfully, please check whether the CSS file is in the site folder, also you could try to use the F12 developer tools to check the detailed error message. here is a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704188/sharepoint-foundation-2013-linking-css-files-in-a-site-collection) you could refer to it. Since, it is relates to SharePoint, you could also post this problem in [SharePoint forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?category=sharepoint).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT I opened the Developer Tools and it seems I'm getting a SEC7111 error with the CSS file that is linked. Most of the troubleshooting for this I'm finding for this however is related to http links and nothing with files.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways that you can use to solve your problem (It's better to share your code within your question to get a better answer). So, I offer you below solutions:

> Solution 1

Please don't use `file://` for the published site in the webserver. HTML rendered on the client so you cannot access the local files. so you should not use the `file://`. you can read more about security concerns and more details on the file protocol here: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

Instead of using `local file protocol`, you can use the `Absolute/Relative path to your CSS` on the HTTP/HTTPS protocols

> Solution 2

Add `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag or `HTTP response header` to force IE to run with legacy document mode: `5`, `7`, `8`.

**X-UA-Compatible meta tag:**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
    ...
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**X-UA-Compatible HTTP response header:**

[image]